# How to display correct resource language base on culture in .NET Core - Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-localization

I have an issue with language resource is not display correct value base on the culture, I have no problem with **ASP.NET Core Web Application**, however in the **Web API** it's not working correctly.

Library => .NET Core 3.1 - Class Library

[image: 1]

Language.resx and Language.vi.resx

[image: 2]

Web API => .NET Core 3.1

The localization middleware is enabled in the Startup.Configure method as below:

[image: 3]

Then in controller, I'm have an action to get the current culture and the value of the resource, however it's always return the value of English

https://localhost:5051/api/home/test?culture=en-US

[image: 4]

https://localhost:5051/api/home/test?culture=vi-VN

[image: 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure localization in ASP.Net Core Web API a little bit different.

Frist of all, the main issue with folder naming and controller. You need to have the same resource naming and controller. More about in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-file-naming). Also, resource folder should be in the same project of ASP.Net Core Web API.

For example: **HomeController** and **Resources/Controllers.HomeController.en-US.resx** or **Resources/Controllers/HomeController.en-US.resx**

I have created new ASP.Net Core Web API project and do the following steps:

1. In `ConfigureServices()` add this code:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => 
{
    var supportedCulters = new List<CultureInfo>()
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCulters.FirstOrDefault());
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCulters;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCulters;
});
```

2. In `Configure()` add this code:

```
var requestLocalizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions.Value);
```

3. Create new resources **Resources/Controllers/HomeController.en-US.resx** and **Resources/Controllers/HomeController.fr-FR.resx**
4. Add the following code in `HomeController`:

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;
public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var currentLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    var result = $"{currentLanguage}-{_localizer["Hello"].Value}";
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Finally, it works correct.

English text

[image: English]

France text

[image: France]

### Solution for Localized Resource in Separate Assembly

Do the following steps:

1. Create empty class `Language` in folder `Resources` in your seperate project.
2. Create **Language.en-US.resx** and **Language.fr-FR.resx**

[image: Language]

3. Inject in `HomeController` following code

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<Language> _localizer;
public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<Language> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}
```

Finally, it works correct for separate assembly project.

Comment: Thanks for your help DarkSideMoon, the reason why I didn't put the resource in the same Web API project because it's share resource and I need to use it in another project.

Comment: @GaruJwon I updated my answer about resource in separate assembly.